# Polynomial divided by a monomial in some extended Collatz Shortcut function

Tags: polynomials, collatz-conjecture

Quirks of the Collatz shortcut function.
*One example and some basic questions.*

The functions here are defined as:

$$C_d(n):\mathbb{Z^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z^+}$$
$$n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$$

*The definition of stopping time (in this text) is the time it takes for the iterates to reach 1.*

As I mostly study in base $2$, I use $(-1)^x$ for parity checking when translating to base $10$. $x$ is always an integer, so a fraction will be floored with integer division. I'd like to note with subscript of the function - the largest exponent to the power of $2$ that divides $3n+1$. I.e the standard shortcut function I note shortcut$_{2}$ function or $C_{2}(n)$ because it divides one time (since $3n+1$ always is even). If is twice even we can divide by $4$ (i.e. two times) so shortcut$_{4}$ or $C_{4}(n)$. So basically we can divide "up" by $4$. So $d$ is the largest power of $2$ in $C_d$. Note I also use $:=$ to show the trajectory of $C_d$.

**Standard shortcut form of the Collatz function**

Define $C_2$ to be:
$$C_2(n) = \begin{cases} n/2 &\text{if } n \equiv 0 \\ (3n+1)/2 & \text{if } n\equiv 1\end{cases} \pmod{2}.$$

To recap
the standard Shortcut$_{2}$ function when $n=27$ has stopping time of $70$:

$C(27)_{2}:=27\rightarrow41\rightarrow62\rightarrow31\rightarrow47\rightarrow71\rightarrow107\rightarrow161\rightarrow242\rightarrow121\rightarrow182\rightarrow91\rightarrow137\rightarrow206\rightarrow103\rightarrow155\rightarrow233\rightarrow350\rightarrow175\rightarrow263\rightarrow395\rightarrow593\rightarrow890\rightarrow445\rightarrow668\rightarrow334\rightarrow167\rightarrow251\rightarrow377\rightarrow566\rightarrow283\rightarrow425\rightarrow638\rightarrow319\rightarrow479\rightarrow719\rightarrow1079\rightarrow1619\rightarrow2429\rightarrow3644\rightarrow1822\rightarrow911\rightarrow1367\rightarrow2051\rightarrow3077\rightarrow4616\rightarrow2308\rightarrow1154\rightarrow577\rightarrow866\rightarrow433\rightarrow650\rightarrow325\rightarrow488\rightarrow244\rightarrow122\rightarrow61\rightarrow92\rightarrow46\rightarrow23\rightarrow35\rightarrow53\rightarrow80\rightarrow40\rightarrow20\rightarrow10\rightarrow5\rightarrow8\rightarrow4\rightarrow2\rightarrow1.$

**Expanded form of the shortcut function**

From the polynomial of degree $1$ divided by a monomial I found this expression:
$$\frac{a+b+3c+7}{4}$$

All divisions are done with integer division. So we can use the floor function.

Then let
$$a = (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{9n+3}{4}\rfloor}$$
$$b = (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{3n+1}{4}\rfloor}$$
$$c = (-1)^{\lfloor\frac{3n+1}{2}\rfloor}$$

$$C_{8}(n) = \frac{3n+1} {2^{\lfloor\frac{a + b + 3c+7}{4}\rfloor} } $$

we insert $a$, $b$ and $c$ and also account for even versus odd $n$'s:

$$C_8(n) = \begin{cases}{n/2}&\text{if } n \equiv 0\pmod{2} \\{\frac{3n+1}{2^{\lfloor\frac{{(-1)^{{\lfloor\frac{9n+3}{4}\rfloor}} + (-1)^{{\lfloor\frac{3n+1}{4}\rfloor}} + 3(-1)^{\lfloor\frac{3n+1}{2}\rfloor}+7}}{4}\rfloor} }}&\text{if } n\equiv 1\pmod{2}\end{cases}$$

For odd $n$'s here's the boolean expression in C-language:

```
(3*n+1)>>((-2*(-6+3*(1&(3*n+1)>>1)+(1&(3*n+1)>>2)+(1&(3+9*n)>>2)))>>2)
```

*The boolean expression was fully simplified with Wolfram Alpha.*

Now this exploited Shortcut$_{8}$ function when $n=27$ gives stopping time of $46$:

$C(27)_{8}:=27\rightarrow41\rightarrow31\rightarrow47\rightarrow71\rightarrow107\rightarrow161\rightarrow121\rightarrow91\rightarrow137\rightarrow103\rightarrow155\rightarrow233\rightarrow175\rightarrow263\rightarrow395\rightarrow593\rightarrow445\rightarrow167\rightarrow251\rightarrow377\rightarrow283\rightarrow425\rightarrow319\rightarrow479\rightarrow719\rightarrow1079\rightarrow1619\rightarrow2429\rightarrow911\rightarrow1367\rightarrow2051\rightarrow3077\rightarrow1154\rightarrow577\rightarrow433\rightarrow325\rightarrow122\rightarrow61\rightarrow23\rightarrow35\rightarrow53\rightarrow20\rightarrow10\rightarrow5\rightarrow2\rightarrow1$

Even thought the above expression looks more complicated it does some more shortcuts. I can now divide up to $8$. This can also be extended to $16$,$32$,$64..$ and so on, but it gets even more complicated.
I have not found a more general polynom or expression for the highest exponent $y$ to the power of $2$ that divides $3n+1$.
Does it exist? Can a polynomial of integer coefficients have infinite terms?

There are a more clean expression than the one above but where the degree of the polynom increases as the number of divisions of $2$ increases, but extending it to reach all odds up to a certain limit causes the formula to be quite big and messy.

Can I ask wether a polynomial of degree one with infinite terms divided by a monomial exist for a power of two exponent that divides $3n+1$? Or does not such polynomial exist?

I need someone to confirm that this Collatz shortcut function: $C_8$ (that is for divisions up to $8$) does indeed work.

Comment: hmm, just a short question: I didn't see any reflection of the possibility that the exponents $(9x+3)/4$ etc might become fractional. I didn't check, but doesn't this happen perhaps? Then what is $(-1)$ to a fractional power?

Comment: @GottfriedHelms oh. well, maybe I wasn't clear about that. $n$ is integer, so every division are integer division. I tested this formula with computer code so thats why the result is floored or truncated, since every integer is positive. Im not confident on the mathematical notation on this. Maybe $n\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ and $C:\mathbb{Z^+}\rightarrow\mathbb{Z^+}$

Comment: yepp, I understand. Perhaps simply $\text{floor}((9x+3)/4)$ or with symbols $\left \lfloor {9x+3 \over 4} \right \rfloor $ . Or $\left[{9x+3 \over 4} \right]$ with explanation "*where $[ \cdot ]$ means the integer part*" or so. (Don't know the most professional expression though)

Comment: I see now your intention. A further easier notation might be the "Iverson-bracket", introduced for instance in the programming-language "APL" but also elsewhere and also in generalizations. I used sometimes the notation $[a:b]$ giving $[a:b]=1$ if $b$ divides $a$ and $[a:b]=0$ if not. Then your $(-1)^{...}$ could be written as $2 \cdot [9x+3:4] - 1$ or you could even adapt the whole expression to an even shorter notation. Just an idea though ...

Comment: I don't use APL, but I use C so I added the C-code for odd $n$'s. Im not necessarily interested in providing too much code here since math.stackexchange is for mathematics. Im also here to learn math notation and provide insight into how to write math and maybe also collaborate with mathematicians on this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First*** I'm checking your proposal of the first three functions
$$    \begin{array} {} 
        a(n) &=& \left \lfloor  {9n+3 \over 4} \right  \rfloor  &  \\  
        b(n) &=&\left  \lfloor  {3n +  1 \over 4} \right \rfloor  &\\
        c(n) &=&\left  \lfloor  {3n + 1 \over 2 }\right \rfloor  & \\
 \text{ and} \\
        s(n) &=&\Large\left  \lfloor  {(-1)^{a(n)} + (-1)^{b(n)} + 3(-1)^{c(n)} + 7 \over 4} \right \rfloor \end{array} \\
$$

Used in Pari/GP:

```
 a(n)= floor( (9*n+3 )/4)
 b(n)= floor( (3*n+1 )/4)
 c(n)= floor( (3*n+1 )/2)

 s(n) =floor( ((-1)^a(n)+(-1)^b(n) + 3*(-1)^c(n)+7)/4)

 forstep(n=1,63,2, print([n,3*n+1,2^s(n),"|"])) \\ to be formatted into 2 columns
```

This gives the following protocol:

```
 odd n      |    odd n     |
            |              |
 n 3n+1  den|   n 3n+1  den| "den" means denominator.
-------------------------------- 
 1    4  4  |   3   10  2  | 
 5   16  8  |   7   22  2  |
 9   28  4  |  11   34  2  |
13   40  8  |  15   46  2  |
17   52  4  |  19   58  2  |
21   64  8  |  23   70  2  |
25   76  4  |  27   82  2  |
29   88  8  |  31   94  2  |
33  100  4  |  35  106  2  |
37  112  8  |  39  118  2  |
41  124  4  |  43  130  2  |
45  136  8  |  47  142  2  |
49  148  4  |  51  154  2  |
53  160  8  |  55  166  2  |
57  172  4  |  59  178  2  |
61  184  8  |  63  190  2  |
```

***Now a bit analysis.*** Let's write $e(n)$ if we talk generally about one of the three first functions.

First, we observe that the functions $a(n),b(n),c(n)$ are used only as exponents at $(-1)$ so each $(-1)^{e(n)}$ gives only periodically with increasing $n$ only $2$ values, and we can as well use the modular residue $\pmod 2$ of the floor expressions.
Since we have $3$ functions $e(n)$ we can generate at most $8$ different combinations and can thus code the sum $s(n)$ by evaluating the $8$ residue classes of $n \pmod 8$ only.

So we can look at the functions $e(n)$ when $n=8k+r$ and get

$$    \begin{array} {}    a(8k+r) &=& \left \lfloor 18k + {9r+3 \over 4} \right  \rfloor  &\pmod {2}  \\  
    b(8k+r) &=&\left  \lfloor \phantom 1 6k + {3r +  1 \over 4} \right \rfloor  &\pmod {2}   \\
    c(8k+r) &=&\left  \lfloor 12k + {3r + 1 \over 2 }\right \rfloor  &\pmod {2}  \end{array} $$

We see that the result is independent from the $k$-term because it is integer, can be taken out of the floor and is then congruent to zero by $\pmod 2$.

So indeed we can look at the $8$ residues of $n \pmod 8$ only and the empirical test for the $4$ odd residue classes $ n \pmod 8$ show (for instance in the above protocol) that your coding of the problem is valid.

> ***This answers*** the last question of your post ***to the positive***.

---

***Second*** a way to better generalizability.
There is another scheme to arrive at your $C_8()$ function and which is more obvious how to be generalized.

We establish the following actiontable with the function $\nu_2^*(x)=\min(3,\nu_2(x))$ giving the exponent to which the prime $2$ is factor of $x$ but restricted to a max value of $3$ (because we want look at this modulo $8$ here) .
$$ \begin{array} {r|r|r|r|r|r|r}
 n & n^* & \nu_2^*(n^*)   && n & n^* & \nu_2^*(n^*) \\
   &\Tiny =n  &                &&   & \Tiny =3n+1 &            \\ \hline  
 0& 0& 3 && 1 & 4 & 2 \\\
 2&2 & 1 && 3 & 10 & 1\\\
 4&4 & 2 && 5 & 16 & 3\\\
 6&6 & 1 && 7 & 22 & 1\\\
\end{array} $$

We can now define for the even and odd residue classes using the $\text{mod}$ symbol for getting the modular residue as in some programming languages reproducing the $\nu^*()$ values by sum-of-floors, let's denote them as $E_\text{even}(n)$ and $E_\text{odd}(n)$ for even and odd $n$ respectively:
$$ E_\text{even}(n) = 1
+ \left \lfloor 1- {n \text{ mod } 4 \over 4} \right \rfloor
+ \left \lfloor 1- {n \text{ mod } 8 \over 8} \right \rfloor \\\
 E_\text{odd}(n) = 1 
+ \left \lfloor 1- {n -1 \text{ mod } 4 \over 4} \right \rfloor
+ \left \lfloor 1- {n -5 \text{ mod } 8 \over 8} \right \rfloor 
$$

With this one can define the $C_8()$-transformation either
$$ C_8(n) =  \begin{cases} 
            {n \over 2} & \text { if $n$ is even}  \\\ 
            {3n+1 \over 2^{E_\text{odd}(n)}} & \text { if $n$ is odd}  
    \end{cases} $$
or
$$ C_8(n) =  \begin{cases} 
            {n \over 2^{E_\text{even}(n)}} & \text { if $n$ is even}  \\\
            {3n+1 \over 2^{E_\text{odd}(n)}} & \text { if $n$ is odd}  
    \end{cases} $$

This way of defining seems meaningful for me especially when one wants to generalize to larger modules.

<sub>*additional remark* 
using the "iverson-bracket" in the following form $\displaystyle [a:b]= \begin{cases} 1& \text{ if $b$ divides $a$ } \\ 0 & \text{ else } \end{cases}$ then we have the much much shorter notation
$$ \begin{array}{} E_\text{even}(n) &= 1 & + [n:4]& + [n:8] \\
 E_\text{odd}(n) &= 1 &+[n-5:4] &+ [n-5:8]  \end{array}
$$
and the way to generalization to larger moduli is immediately obvious</sub>

---

***Third*** the generalization using the "actiontable" allows also to define ***polynomials*** (which you mentioned in your question as well) instead. In Pari/GP this can be done by the `polinterpolate()` function and gives

```
pol_e=polinterpolate([0,2,4,6],[3,1,2,1])
pol_o=polinterpolate([1,3,5,7],[2,1,3,1])

\\ here we get
\\ pol_e : -5/48*x^3 + x^2 - 31/12*x + 3
\\ pol_o : -7/48*x^3 + 27/16*x^2 - 257/48*x + 93/16

\\ making polynomial functions
E_even(n) = n=n % 8 ; return(-5/48*n^3 + n^2 - 31/12*n + 3 );
E_odd(n)  = n=n % 8 ; return(-7/48*n^3 + 27/16*n^2 - 257/48*n + 93/16);
\\ alternatively
\\  E_odd(n) = E_even(n-5)
```